# Acknowledging data sources used for creating an image

Tags: citations, citation-style

For a conference paper, I created an image compiling data from multiple sources. What is the correct format for acknowledging the sources?

Map showing road condition (Data source: Esri, OpenStreetMap) or,

Map showing road condition (Data source**s**: Esri, OpenStreetMap)

In most of the literature, I observed authors commonly using 'source' when they mean 'sources'. Shouldn't it be 'sources'?

Comment: Unless there is some standard that I am unaware of in a domain specific application, either should be fine. Such semantic details are unlikely to affect the validity of your paper. In fact, if they do, someone needs to settle down.

Comment: I had to look at it three times to see the difference. I think few would notice and fewer would care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the choice is likely arbitrary since it will not affect the readability of your article much.

If you want to keep the formulation as is, I would personally go with "Data sources" as I think it makes more linguistic sense. If I would ask the reader to check out two published articles, I would write: "see the **papers** by [Uncle Tom Cobley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncle_Tom_Cobley) (1889) and [Alan Smithee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Smithee) (1968)" and not "see the **paper** by Uncle Tom Cobley (1889) and Alan Smithee (1968).". Similarly, I would write "see the data sources Esri and OpenStreetMap" and not "see the data source Esri and OpenStreetMap".

However, one possible workaround would be to side-step the issue by chosing a different formulation. For instance, perhaps by writing "Data from",  or just simply "Data".

Answer (score 0):

As long as you give proper credit to all images you’ve used and have not violated their terms of use, I see no reason why anyone would mind (or notice!) a little ‘s’.

Comment: While I agree with your statement here, I would like to add that I think the question is within the scope of this stackexchange site.